# SwiftUI & UDP listener - data not updating in the ContentView

Tags: swift, sockets, swiftui, udp

I have an app where I have to receive a string over the network and the string is being sent by an Raspberry Pi Nano over UDP protocol.
I took an example from an article where there is a setup for listener on certain port.
The thing is that I receive the data successfully and once I convert it to a string I would like to update the view ... but the view never updates.
Any good suggestions?
Here is the code:
UDPSocketManager

```
//
//  SocketManager.swift
//  SocketUDPTest
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 27.08.23.
//


import Foundation
import Network
import Combine


class UDPListener: ObservableObject {
    
    var listener: NWListener?
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    
    /// New data will be place in this variable to be received by observers
    @Published private(set) public var messageReceived: Data?
    /// When there is an active listening NWConnection this will be `true`
    @Published private(set) public var isReady: Bool = false
    /// Default value `true`, this will become false if the UDPListener ceases listening for any reason
    @Published public var listening: Bool = true
    
    @Published public var nmeaString: String = "hello there"
    
    /// A convenience init using Int instead of NWEndpoint.Port
    convenience init(on port: Int) {
        self.init(on: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: NWEndpoint.Port.IntegerLiteralType(port)))
    }
    /// Use this init or the one that takes an Int to start the listener
    init(on port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        
        let params = NWParameters.udp
        params.allowFastOpen = true
        self.listener = try? NWListener(using: params, on: port)
        self.listener?.stateUpdateHandler = { update in
            switch update {
            case .ready:
                self.isReady = true
                print("Listener connected to port \(port)")
            case .failed, .cancelled:
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
                self.isReady = false
                print("Listener disconnected from port \(port)")
            default:
                print("Listener connecting to port \(port)...")
            }
        }
        self.listener?.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
            print("Listener receiving new message")
            self.createConnection(connection: connection)
        }
        self.listener?.start(queue: self.queue)
    }
    
    func createConnection(connection: NWConnection) {
        self.connection = connection
        self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                print("Listener ready to receive message")
                self.receive()
            case .cancelled, .failed:
                print("Listener failed to receive message")
                // Cancel the listener, something went wrong
                self.listener?.cancel()
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
            default:
                print("Listener waiting to receive message")
            }
        }
        self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
    }
    
    func receive() {
        self.connection?.receiveMessage { data, context, isComplete, error in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print("Error: NWError received in \(#function) - \(unwrappedError)")
                return
            }
            guard isComplete, let data = data else {
                print("Error: Received nil Data with context - \(String(describing: context))")
                return
            }
            self.messageReceived = data // <-- here I receive the data
        
//data is converted to a string which is @Published, so I can use it in later stage
//I can see the string being printed in the console

            self.nmeaString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
            print(self.nmeaString)
            if self.listening {
                self.receive()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.listening = false
        self.connection?.cancel()
    }
    
    
}
```

Then I have a simple view just for test:

```
//
//  NMEAStringDisplay.swift
//  SocketUDPTest
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 27.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct NMEAStringDisplay: View {
    
    var message: String = "why why?"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                
                let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
                let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 20)
                Text(message)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .offset(x: width/2, y: height/4)
            }.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}

struct NMEAStringDisplay_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NMEAStringDisplay(message: "hello")
    }
}
```

And at the end this view is called in content view, where "udpscoket" is an observed object and the view where the string should update is called with "udpsocket.nmeaString" which is the before mentioned @Published string.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SocketUDPTest
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 27.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Network

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var udpsocket = UDPListener(on: 4950)
    
    var body: some View {
 
        VStack{
            NMEAStringDisplay(message: udpsocket.nmeaString)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

EDIT #1 - Updated Code for Socket Manager
So, thanks all for the good advices. I followed all of them.
changed connection and listener to be non-optional and initialise the properly (according to me, please tell if I am wrong).
After that, before I assign the value to "nmeaString" I switch to main thread and corrected the object ot be "@StateObject" instead of observed object. I also change the content view to pretty simple:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SocketUDPTest
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 27.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Network

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var udpsocket = UDPListener(on: 4950)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(udpsocket.nmeaString)

    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

However, it still doesn't show the text in the View? What am I missing?
here is the updated code for SocketManager:

```
import Foundation
import Network


class UDPListener: ObservableObject {
    
    var listener: NWListener
    var connection: NWConnection
    var queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    /// New data will be place in this variable to be received by observers
    @Published private(set) public var messageReceived: Data?
    /// When there is an active listening NWConnection this will be `true`
    @Published private(set) public var isReady: Bool = false
    /// Default value `true`, this will become false if the UDPListener ceases listening for any reason
    @Published public var listening: Bool = true
    
    @Published var nmeaString: String = "hello"
    
    /// A convenience init using Int instead of NWEndpoint.Port
    convenience init(on port: Int) {
        self.init(on: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: NWEndpoint.Port.IntegerLiteralType(port)))
    }
    /// Use this init or the one that takes an Int to start the listener
    init(on port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        let params = NWParameters.udp
        //params.allowFastOpen = true
        self.connection = NWConnection(host: "192.168.8.1", port: 4950, using: .udp)
        self.listener = try!NWListener(using: params, on: port)
        self.listener.stateUpdateHandler = { update in
            switch update {
            case .ready:
                self.isReady = true
                print("Listener connected to port \(port)")
            case .failed, .cancelled:
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
                self.isReady = false
                print("Listener disconnected from port \(port)")
            default:
                print("Listener connecting to port \(port)...")
            }
        }
        self.listener.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
            print("Listener receiving new message")
            self.createConnection(connection: connection)
        }
        self.listener.start(queue: self.queue)
    }
    
    func createConnection(connection: NWConnection) {
        self.connection = connection
        self.connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                print("ready")
                //start receiving messages here
                self.receive()
            case .cancelled, .failed:
                print("Listener failed to receive message - \(connection)")
                // Cancel the listener, something went wrong
                self.listener.cancel()
                // Announce we are no longer able to listen
                self.listening = false
            default:
                print("waiting")
            }
        }
        self.connection.start(queue: .global())
    }
    
    func receive() {
        self.connection.receiveMessage { data, context, isComplete, error in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print("Error: NWError received in \(#function) - \(unwrappedError)")
                return
            }
            guard isComplete, let data = data else {
                print("Error: Received nil Data with context - \(String(describing: context))")
                return
            }
            
            //go to main thread and update nmeaString value
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                //self.messageReceived = data
                self.nmeaString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                print(self.nmeaString)
                
                
            }
            
            //this is ok, in case connection false it will alert me
            if self.listening {
                self.receive()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.listening = false
        self.connection.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `@StateObject` not `@ObservedObject`

Comment: Also, if you're receiving on a background thread, you should switch to the main thread before updating a `@Published` property

Comment: take jnpdx advice **and** try using a different offset in `Text(message).offset(...)`
 and you will see the message. Also try to actually use the `geometry`, such as  `let width = geometry.size.width` etc...

Comment: Your error handling in your class UDPListener is rather lacking. You should improve this: `listener` and `connection` MUST be initialised correctly. So, your listener is not optional, make it `let`. Then, use `var connection: NWConnection!`, i.e. an _implicitly unwrapped_, because it's not _optional_ and must be non nil after a correct initialisation. Next, handle all error states _explicitly_, i.e. don't use `try?`.  Also, a better design is making `UDPListener` an _underlying_ layer for your ObservableObject and name your ObservableObject _what_ it does, not _how_ it does something.

Comment: Thanks all for the good suggestions. However, I applied them all and yet I can't get the text to be shown in the view. I think something is missing in the observed / state object pattern relation. What am I missing? Any suggestions are welcome - I would really much appreciate some really simple but reliable structure of how to setup the UDP listener, thanks. I have tried to do it from the apple docs but I got confused at some point and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
So, I found a post in another article where the guy had exactly the same issue. His solution was to declare a singleton class in the UDPManager class and the access the @Published var via the singleton class.
I did the same thing and text appeared in the content view.
Although, I am very happy about it I couldn't understand exactly why is accessible via a singleton but not via a standard reference to the @Published var.
If someone shares an explanation will be very useful.
However here is the code that you need to add in order to make it work as I wanted.

```
//declare a singleton class in SocketManager file
static let sharedInstance = UDPListener(on: 4950)


//use access the @Published var nmeaString via the singleton in the ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var udpsocket = UDPListener.sharedInstance
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(self.udpsocket.nmeaString)
            

    }
}
```